# Implementing my Point and Line class using OOP - Error: null pointer exception

Tags: java, oop

I am trying to write my own Point and Line class (although the similar code could be found online).
I am doing this to practice how to build a basic code from the scratch.
I got a null pointer exception error and I would like someone to help me point out what I am doing wrong and how to fix this issue here. thank you!

This is my Point class:

```
public class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;

public Point() {
    this.x = 0.0;
    this.y = 0.0;
}
public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
public void setX(double x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
}
public double getX() {
    return this.x;
}
public double getY() {
    return this.y;
}
public String toString() {
    return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point p = new Point(1.5, 3);
        System.out.println(p.toString());
}
```

}

This is my Line class:

```
public class Line {
    private Point p1;
    private Point p2;

public Line() {
    p1 = new Point(0,0);
    p2 = new Point(0,0);
}

public Line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    p1 = new Point(x1, y1);
    p2 = new Point(x2, y2);
}
public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
    p1 = new Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
    p2 = new Point(p2.getX(), p2.getY());
}
public Point getP1() {
    return this.p1;
}
public Point getP2() {
    return this.p2;
}
public void setP1(double x, double y) {
    this.p1 = new Point (x, y);
}
public void setP2(double x, double y) {
    this.p2 = new Point(x, y);
}
public double getSlope() {
    return ((p2.getY() - p1.getY()) / (p2.getX() - p1.getX()));
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point p1 = new Point(0, 3);
    Point p2 = new Point(5, 5);
    Line l = new Line(p1, p2);
    System.out.println(l.getSlope()); //Threw an error at this point!!
}
```

}
I got null pointer exception error for my line class even though my point is class is ok. 
Could someone please explain to me how to fix the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this.p1/p2, because here you are only changing the parameters of the constructor.

```
public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
  this.p1 = new Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY());
  this.p2 = new Point(p2.getX(), p2.getY());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But the same problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

**NO changes are required to Point class source code**

```
 public class Point { 
      private double x;
      private double y;

    public Point() {
        this.x = 0.0;
        this.y = 0.0;
    }
    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return this.y;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p = new Point(1.5, 3);
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
}
```

**Please change your code in the Line class as below**

```
public class Line {
     private Point p1;
     private Point p2;

    public Line() {
        p1 = new Point(0,0);
        p2 = new Point(0,0);
    }

    public Line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
        p1 = new Point(x1, y1);
        p2 = new Point(x2, y2);
    }
    public Line(Point p1, Point p2) {
        this. p1 = new Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY());//add this.p1 instead of p1
        this.p2 = new Point(p2.getX(), p2.getY());//add this.p2 intead of p2
    }
    public Point getP1() {
        return this.p1;
    }
    public Point getP2() {
        return this.p2;
    }
    public void setP1(double x, double y) {
        this.p1 = new Point (x, y);
    }
    public void setP2(double x, double y) {
        this.p2 = new Point(x, y);
    }
    public double getSlope() {
        return ((p2.getY() - p1.getY()) / (p2.getX() - p1.getX()));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p1 = new Point(0, 3);
        Point p2 = new Point(5, 5);
        Line l = new Line(p1, p2);
        System.out.println(l.getSlope()); //Threw an error at this point!!
    }
}
```

**Outout for given inputs:0.4**

**Explanation:**
You are trying to assign your p1 and p2 reference variables(which are method parameters in the two argument overloaded Line constructor) to your instance variables of the class p1 and p2.But in this case your method also contains the same name method parameters as the instance varibales in the class so in that case your method parameters won't get assigned to the instance variables of your class.The objects which are generate after the new Point(p1.getX(), p1.getY()) and new Point(p2.getX(), p2.getY()) will be assigned again to the method parameters p1 and p2.

**SOLUTION 1:(Which I did in the above code)**
If you are using the same name in the instance variables and the method parameters then use **this keyword** in the cases of dealing with instance variables.

**SOLUTION 2:**
**use different variable names** to method parameters and instance variables.